# How to print subfolder data while fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am new to web development and learning how to use API. I am using this rapid API and would like to print only the default url instead of the whole json file. Please help

This is the body file from rapid API

```
"Item":[18 items
0:{8 items
"name":"Top News"
"defaultname":"Top News"
"defaulturl":"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsdefaultfeeds.cms?feedtype=sjson"
"sectionurl":"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/feedurllist.cms?category=topnews"
"subsections":"no"
"template":"headlines"
"Icon":""
"ID":"Top-01"
}
1:{8 items
"name":"City"
"defaultname":"All Cities"
"defaulturl":"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsfeed/-2128932452.cms?feedtype=sjson"
"sectionurl":"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/feedurllist.cms?category=city"
"subsections":"yes"
"template":"news"
"Icon":""
"ID":"City-01"
}
```

here is my script

```
async function fetchnews(){

  const fetchresult=fetch("https://devru-times-of-india.p.rapidapi.com/feeds/feedurllist.cms?catagory=city%252FItem%252Fdefaulturl", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "devru-times-of-india.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "2406d619fbmsh3e12d4fa0d35484p1c63c9jsn0404e4a39e3b"
    }
  })
  response=await fetchresult;
  const data=await response.json();
  console.log(data); 

}
fetchnews();
```

here is the console output(I just want to print defaulturl)

```
Item: (18) […]
​​
0: Object { name: "Top News", defaultname: "Top News", defaulturl: "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsdefaultfeeds.cms?feedtype=sjson", … }
​​
1: Object { name: "City", defaultname: "All Cities", defaulturl: "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsfeed/-2128932452.cms?feedtype=sjson", … }
​​
2: Object { name: "India", defaultname: "India", defaulturl: "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsfeed/-2128936835.cms?feedtype=sjson", … }
​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of your api is `{'Item': [...]}`. It means that you should iterate 'Item' inside the response and extract `defaulturl` from there.

```js
    async function fetchnews(){

      const fetchresult=fetch("https://devru-times-of-india.p.rapidapi.com/feeds/feedurllist.cms?catagory=city%252FItem%252Fdefaulturl", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "devru-times-of-india.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "2406d619fbmsh3e12d4fa0d35484p1c63c9jsn0404e4a39e3b"
        }
      })
      response=await fetchresult;
      const data=await response.json();
      
      for(item of data.Item) {
        console.log(item.defaulturl);
      }
    }
    fetchnews();
```